# CSS:hover Issue when trying to display hidden textbox

Tags: css

Right, I am currently building my own website for a bit of fun and I am trying to create a box that when hovered on will display "x" information. However, for the life of me I cannot get the box to display.

I thought I might aswell mention that I have already achieved something similar to this, except, in this example I am hovering on an image instead of a piece of text `<p>`

Also, whenever I hover over where the textbox would appear it works?!?! This has really got me confused!

Here is my code:

```css
#siteHover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  width: 475px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#siteHover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitevAlign">
  <p id="siteHover">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: #siteHover p:hover should be #siteHover:hover

Comment: I realised this lol, however, the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: how to hover an invsible element? we need to guess where is it first ... and it's at the very bottom of the page

Comment: @TemaniAfif actually you can if it is hidden with just opacity since the element keeps his box dimensions and space. The problem here is more related with the absolute position and coords that is been used

Comment: Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/dtfLtcom/

Comment: @DaniP I know and still the issue how to hover an invisible element ;) it doesn't make sense for me ... we need something intuitive, we hover something we see ... we add at least a border or something so we know

Comment: Sure @TemaniAfif that will be adress more a UX problem :) ...

Comment: @JShepherd Can you take a look at my answer below and tell me if that is correct? If so, can you mark the answer that helped answer your question as the accepted answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

If you need help understanding what each bit of code does, feel free to ask any questions :)

```css
.sitevAlign {
  height: 100px;
  width: 475px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: steelblue;
}

#siteHover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

.sitevAlign:hover #siteHover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitevAlign">
  <p id="siteHover">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're pushing `div.sitevAlign` 150% from the top so you can't really hover over it until you scroll down to it, try scrolling down and put your mouse in the middle horizontally.

Would be better if you'd remove it that `top:150%`

```css
#siteHover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  width: 475px;
  padding: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#siteHover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitevAlign">
  <p id="siteHover">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
</div>
```

As a side note it would be better if you'd let the user know where to hover.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sitevAlign {
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#siteHover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  width: 475px;
  padding: 15px;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}

#siteHover:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sitevAlign">
  <p id="siteHover">This is my primary website where all the information you might require on me is available! This site is also a demonstration of my work; however, external reviews are available on the website!</p>
</div>
```